# Showing fields or content with Views - which is faster?

Tags: 7, views

Say I'm building a view that lists 30 nodes. My understanding is that using fields in the view is faster than content (teaser), because the latter would need to call node_load 30 times? At least, I think this was the case with D6.

I appreciate the performance of both options depends on number of fields and types of fields used (entity reference, dates etc add query overhead). But does anyone have a general steer on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In D7 it is the same, because the node (or any other parent entity) needs to be loaded in order for a field to be displayed (that's how Field API works in D7).

Comment: To get an appreciable difference in load time, you'd have to skip the View entirely and used [`db_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) to run a custom query from code.

Comment: In which case you wouldn't be able to apply any formatter to a field value, making it almost-useless.

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as I know with cache enabled using teasers is actually faster as teasers can be cached efficiently.